# Calling ReadProcessorPwrScheme() does not return correct values

Tags: c#, power-management

I would like to ask a question regarding P/Invoke method. I am coding in C# and would like to access the Power Management API (powrprof.dll) method "ReadProcessorPwrScheme". Unfortunately, I am not getting the correct values and I suspect that I may be a problem in marshaling. Any help is much appreciated. Some of the codes that I have:

```
struct PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY_INFO
{
    public uint TimeCheck;                  // ULONG
    public uint DemoteLimit;                // ULONG
    public uint PromoteLimit;               // ULONG
    public byte DemotePercent;
    public byte PromotePercent;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public byte[] Spare;
    public uint AllowDemotion;
    public uint AllowPromotion;
    public uint Reserved;
}

struct PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY
{
    public uint Revision;                   // DWORD
    public byte DynamicThrottle;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public byte[] Spare;
    public uint DisableCStates;             // DWORD
    public uint Reserved;                   // DWORD
    public uint PolicyCount;                // DWORD
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY_INFO[] Policy;
}

struct MACHINE_PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY
{
    public uint Revision;                   // ULONG
    public PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY ProcessorPolicyAc;
    public PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY ProcessorPolicyDc;
}


[DllImport("powrprof.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ReadProcessorPwrScheme(uint uiID, out MACHINE_PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY pMachineProcessorPowerPolicy);
public void ReadProcessorPowerScheme()
{
    MACHINE_PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY mppp = new MACHINE_PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY();
    uint schemeID0 = 0;

    if (ReadProcessorPwrScheme(schemeID0, out mppp))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mppp.ProcessorPolicyAc.DynamicThrottle);
        Console.WriteLine(mppp.ProcessorPolicyDc.DynamicThrottle);
    }
}
```

**mppp.ProcessorPolicyAc.DynamicThrottle** is showing the correct value but **mppp.ProcessorPolicyDc.DynamicThrottle** is not showing the correct value. Anyone has any hint or idea whats wrong?

Additional info: This is run on Win XP

Comment: please don't put tags like "C#:" in the title. Just leave them in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my question. It was my misunderstanding about the struct definition which causes the wrong bytes to be read. The correct struct definition is as below.

```
struct PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY_INFO 
{ 
    public uint TimeCheck;                  // ULONG 
    public uint DemoteLimit;                // ULONG 
    public uint PromoteLimit;               // ULONG 
    public byte DemotePercent; 
    public byte PromotePercent; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)] 
    public byte[] Spare; 
    //public uint AllowDemotion; 
    //public uint AllowPromotion; 
    //public uint Reserved; 
    public uint AllowBits;
} 

struct PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY 
{ 
    public uint Revision;                   // DWORD 
    public byte DynamicThrottle; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)] 
    public byte[] Spare; 
    //public uint DisableCStates;             // DWORD 
    public uint Reserved;                   // DWORD 
    public uint PolicyCount;                // DWORD 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)] 
    public PROCESSOR_POWER_POLICY_INFO[] Policy; 
}
```